# Measurement of Resistor Parasitics Inductance and Capacitance

Tags: resistors, microwave, parasitic-capacitance, vna, inductance-measurement

I have seen people doing some measurements of parasitic capacitance and inductance of some resistors, by using a vector analyzer and analyzing the graph of S11 with respect to frequency.

To get this measurement they have soldered the resistor to a type N connector, and that connector has been connected to one port of the Vector Analyzer.

My question is: how can this measurement be correct? It is like putting the resistor under test in parallel to a 50Ohm resistance (since the characteristic impedance of the type N connector was 50Ohm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It is like putting the resistor under test in parallel to a 50 ohm
>   resistance (since the characteristic impedance of the type N connector
>   was 50 ohm).

No, that is incorrect; the characteristic impedance of a piece of coax or a connector is a value that is the square root of the inductance to capacitance ratio of the part or cable. It isn't a real value of resistance i.e. if you put 1 volt across an N type connector, 20 mA doesn't flow continuously.

20 mA does flow but, only for a fraction of a nano second or so.

<sub>If you applied 1 volt to an infinitely long piece of coax then 20 mA would flow indefinitely.</sub>

Comment: But can it affect the measurement in some ways?

Comment: It can affect the measurement very slightly in the same way as having slightly longer lead lengths will give a slight parasitic inductance error or, temperature variations affecting the resistance value i.e. it a different temperature produces a slight error.

Answer (score 0):

The characteristic impedance Z (in Ohms) should not be confused with an ordinary impedance R (Ohms).

There‘s no current that can flow through Z because its definition is based on magnetic field H (A/m) and electric field E (V/m), whereas the definition of R is based on voltage (V) and current (A).

Air has a characteristic impedance Z of 377 Ohms, but there is no current flowing through it (except for lightning sparks).

So the measurement is correct because Z is not parallel to R since it is not the same thing.